# How to retain an empty JSON parent object for NULL child values - SQL Server FOR JSON PATH

Tags: json, sql-server, null

I am asking and answering my own question but I would like to see if anyone else has any better idea of how to do this.

I have some JSON that I am sending to a 3rd party API. I have created a fake simplified representation of what I am trying to do.
There is a `primary_selection` with its child elements and a `secondary_selection` with its child elements. If the secondary selection doesn't exist, the child elements are all NULL. According to the API the `secondary_selection` is required but can be empty. They also want NULL elements to be excluded.

```
DECLARE @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS NVARCHAR(500)
SELECT @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS = (
    SELECT '123456' [administrative_info.account_num],
        '1' [administrative_info.user_id],
        'whole wheat bread' [primary_selection.vehicle_for_sauce],
        'avocado' [primary_selection.topping],
        'mayo' [primary_selection.sauce_type],
        NULL [secondary_selection.vehicle_for_mayo],
        NULL [secondary_selection.topping],
        NULL [secondary_selection.sauce_type]
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
SELECT @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS
```

The SQL above produces the following:

```
"administrative_info": {
    account_num": "123456",
    "user_id": "1"
},
"primary_selection": {
    "vehicle_for_sauce": "whole wheat bread",
    "topping": "avocado",
    "sauce_type": "mayo"
}
```

But what I want is:

```
"administrative_info": {
    "account_num": "123456",
    "user_id": "1"
},
"primary_selection": {
    "vehicle_for_sauce": "whole wheat bread",
    "topping": "avocado",
    "sauce_type": "mayo"
},
"secondary_selection": {}
```

Comment: Rather than tagging for loop, which is nowhere to be seen in your posts, tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: I removed the for-loop tag I accidentally added it I think when trying to tag "for json path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible option is the statement below. You need to generate each first-level JSON object using `FOR JSON PATH`.

Note, that you need a `JSON_QUERY()` call to prevent escaping of the special characters. This is explained in the documentation: *JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value. If you're returning results with FOR JSON, and you're including data that's already in JSON format (in a column or as the result of an expression), wrap the JSON data with JSON_QUERY without the path parameter*.

```
DECLARE @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS = (
   SELECT
      administrative_info = JSON_QUERY((
         SELECT '123456' [account_num], '1' [user_id]
         FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      )),
      primary_selection = JSON_QUERY((
         SELECT 'whole wheat bread' [vehicle_for_sauce], 'avocado' [topping], 'mayo' [sauce_type]
         FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      )),
      secondary_selection = JSON_QUERY((
         SELECT NULL [vehicle_for_mayo], NULL [topping], NULL [sauce_type]
         FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      ))
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
```

Result:

```
{
   "administrative_info":{
      "account_num":"123456",
      "user_id":"1"
   },
   "primary_selection":{
      "vehicle_for_sauce":"whole wheat bread",
      "topping":"avocado",
      "sauce_type":"mayo"
   },
   "secondary_selection":{
      
   }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, here is my solution, but want to see if anyone else has any other knowledge on how to do this.

```
    DECLARE @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS NVARCHAR(500)

SELECT @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS = (SELECT '123456' [administrative_info.account_num],
                                     '1' [administrative_info.user_id],
                                     'whole wheat bread' [primary_selection.vehicle_for_sauce],
                                     'avocado' [primary_selection.topping],
                                     'mayo' [primary_selection.sauce_type],
                                     NULL [secondary_selection.vehicle_for_mayo],
                                     NULL [secondary_selection.topping],
                                     NULL [secondary_selection.sauce_type]
                              FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

SELECT @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS



DECLARE @EMPTY_OBJECT NVARCHAR(2) = '{}'
    SELECT @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS,'$.secondary_selection',JSON_QUERY(@EMPTY_OBJECT))

SELECT @JSON_WITHOUT_NULLS
```